# How to create deb package with screenshot for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, screenshot, deb

I've create a deb package using instructions from launchpad and put it in PPA, and I want to include the screenshot to be displayed in SoftwareCenter.

and additionally I want to provide Licence and Updates (when I select my package it show undefined or unknown - I have localized version of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upload a screenshot to http://screenshots.debian.net/ it will be displayed in SoftwareCenter and Synaptic. Although I'm not sure if that applies to packages from PPAs, they might have a different method or no screenshots at all.

Comment: It seams that they are only for debian packages that are also in Ubuntu, so I need to write a package for debian, upload it (mentors.debian.net), and then submit the screenshot.